# Changing an array of arrays to an array of other datatypes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

In Javascript is there a better way to change `[[1],[2],[3]]` to `["1","2","3"]` than what I have done in the code below?

```js
let arr = [[1],[2],[3]];


let newArr = [];
arr.forEach(elem => {
elem.forEach(val=>{
newArr.push(val);
})
})

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: It wowuld help if you add some formatted source code of what you tried, and the result you got so far.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.map()` to convert each array to string using the String [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/String):

```js
const arr = [[1],[2],[3]]

const numbersArr = arr.map(String)

console.log(numbersArr)
```

If you have multiple items in each array, flatten the array, and them map the array items to strings:

```js
const arr = [[1, 2],[2, 3],[3, 4]]

const numbersArr = arr.flat().map(String)

console.log(numbersArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce` to reduce your 2d array into a single array.

```js
const arr = [[1],[2],[3]];

const result = arr.reduce( (acc, cur) => {
  acc.push(cur[0].toString())
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score -1):

It might be helpful.

```js
// [1, [2, [3], [4, [[[5, 6]]]]]] => ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

const flatternArray = (arr) => {
    return arr.flatMap(x => {
      if (Array.isArray(x)) {
        return flatternArray(x)
      } else {
        return x.toString();
      }
    })
  }

  console.log(flatternArray([1, [2, [3], [4, [[[5, 6]]]]]]))
```